# Returning value from Android asynchronous nested class

Tags: java, android, azure, asynchronous

I'm attempting to return a variable from within a nested class in a function as follows:

```
public int getPlan(int planID) {
 int planId;
 TableOperationCallback<Plans> callback = new TableOperationCallback<Plans>() {
          public void onCompleted(Plans plan, Exception exception,ServiceFilterResponse response) {
               if(exception == null){
                    int planId = (int) db.addPlan(plan); //Want to return this value
               } else {
                    Log.e(exception.getMessage(), "ERROR");
               }
          } 
     };
  mPlanTable.lookUp(planID, callback);
  return planId;
}
```

This method is linked with the Azure Android SDK and mPlanTable.lookUp() is called asynchronously. Consequently, `planId` is sometimes returned null with the above code.

What is the best method to return the actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lookUp is asynchronous then you NEVER return its result.  You need to refactor your code so that anything that uses the return value is done in the callback, not there.